# how to select all parent node in xml data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, for-xml-path

i want to select in  all parent node while i don't know how many nodes exist ?

```
    *<TreeView>
          <node  text="a">
            <node text="aa">
              <node text="aaa" />
            </node>
            <node text="b">
              <node text="bb" />
                    </node>
                  </node>
                  <node text="c" />*


        </TreeView> 

    what i want is: a,aa,b
```

Comment: Can you please give a little more insight on which language you are using? How the data is retrieved and what do you want as result?

Comment: i find an answer: xmlNode.SelectNodes("//*[count(child::*)>1]")

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML =  '<TreeView>
          <node  text="a">
            <node text="aa">
              <node text="aaa" />
            </node>
            <node text="b">
              <node text="bb" />
                    </node>
                  </node>
                  <node text="c" />*


        </TreeView> '



       SELECT  @MyXML.value ('(//node/@text)[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)'),
       @MyXML.value ('(//node/@text)[2]', 'VARCHAR(30)'),
       @MyXML.value ('(//node/@text)[4]', 'VARCHAR(30)')
```

Comment: actually i want to select all nodes which dont have any child. i mean all nodes except for child nodes!